# How to log out user from office365 and redirect to a page?

Tags: office365

How can I log out a user from Office365 and redirect him to my app login page afterwards?

I know I can log out the user using this url:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/logout.srf

But I would like to redirect them to a login in my application after he was log out of office365. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used this url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri='your_url'
```

And works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Try if this works for you:

```
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=<return‌​Url>
```

At some point that stopped working, but I found a post that that should have been fixed by now.